Problem when adding shaders to simulate glass
I am trying to get better dispersion glass and was exploring different solutions.
When I tried to do light addition with Principled BSDF shaders, I got a weird lighting as if it were emissive.

When I did it with glass shaders, it was better but very dark in cavities.

Which I assumed is the good old 'infinite ray depth' issue in glass and can be fixed by adding a threshold for transparency :

The normal glass shader looks like that for comparison.

My questions :

for my knowledge, why is the Principled BSDF exhibiting such behavior?
why are additive glass shaders behaving worse than the original? Is it the randomness of rays in the solver not fully matching for each primary color (R,G,B)? But then how to improve it?



it's not just the shader, it's also the light and the light path -> how high did you set the transmission/transparent light path?

For the first case, everything is in the snapshot, it is only Princ. BSDF with 100% transmission.
For the third with the Light path, I considered the physics of reflections and transmissions occuring naturally in glass, up to infinity. See this image (I don't know how to put images in comments) : https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-important-scatter-path-is-shown-here-which-is-caused-by-multiple-reflections-within_fig8_252687360

Complementary comment : the Light path setup considers that after a certain number of reflections/transmissions not so much details are added and that it would require to increase a lot the number of maximum bounces of transmission and glossy, so an arbitrary cutoff is applied after 6 interaction in this case to make the ray transparent instead of becoming dark due to not enough bounce computation.

pls provide blend file so we can check it out and improve it. thx.

File added. Thx.

is this what you wanna achieve? [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/CbbxQWSr.png

Kind of. Above all, I wanted to understand with the PBSDF has this emission-like effect and how to better converge when adding glass shaders after separating light in primary colors. If your image is the answer to this questions, then yes.

ok, sorry, i just hoped you wanna make glass look good ...i am no expert in these "theoretic questions" - sorry for that. I added some light and texture and increased light path ...and then ended up this: [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Tp54RZhJ.jpg

Yes, it's more theoretical indeed. But your image looks very nice! Happy to discover your node setup anyway. Thanks for your contribution!

I have to point that out... You have a weird way to select colors: https://i.imgur.com/xlIzv7v.png

This setup is meant to be able to separate any glass color in the 3 primary colors. It is used in many glass shaders. In this example it is not essential indeed, but not weird nonetheless.

But you can put any color in the glass shaders' color inputs themselves, no need to use two extra nodes just to make sure you have a pure red when you can already put a pure red in the color input. It's like if you used math nodes to make 1 - 1 instead of writing 0 in the Roughness input, it's the same thing at the end, but you wasted resources and you make it harder for you

In order to make a dispersion glass shader (as shown in the accepted answer for example), it is needed actually. You can't just send the main color to the 'red' 'green' and 'blue' glass shaders. As I said, in my question above, it was superfluous, but for the targeted case, it is absolutely necessary.

Oh yes in the case you don't use pure white as main color indeed, my bad.

-- No worries  ;)


Why does your shader with Add Shader is darker ?

By adding together the 3 colored Glass shader, you are asking from Blender to :

Let only red light pass through
And let only green light pass through
And let only blue light pass through

The result is that no light passes through, unlike in the case of a white glass shader. The only light reaching the shadows will be indirect light bouncing from other surfaces, not refracted light.

Why does adding 2 Principled BSDF is emitting light ?

Disclaimer : I'm not 100% sure about that one.
Principled BSDF also have a glossy component. You could bypass it by adding roughness (then glossiness is 0), but then you'd loose the clear glass refractions you currently have. So by adding the shaders, the object emits 2x more light from glossy lightrays.
Custom prism shader
I've build 2 easy shaders. The first one is simple, it works but RGB will be separate and not really realistic. The second one is a bit more complex, using White Noise texture as a base to blur the IOR (credits to this video).



The mapping node is only to translate the white noise for each channel and be sure we don't have some kind of overlap. I think it's useless because of the different IOR.

The first shader is actually exactly the one I mentioned in my question and I also know the second one, but I wasn't asking for shaders proposals. In any case, thanks for the explanations in the first part as that's exactly what I was looking for.

So all the shaders of my question behave how they meant to. It's not a bug.

@JagJB That's right I don't think it's a bug. Cycles is already some years old now, I would expect that kind of bug to be detected by now. But I'm only 80% sure of my answer.

I know it's not the answer, but you wanted my node setup:
here it is:

The "rest" as i wrote in my first comment, are "other" things.
these are my render settings:

light path:

i know, that they don't have to be all 60, but it renders fast anyway.
important are these:

transparent + transparent glass
then i just gave that plane a shader, added 3 lamps and a background hdri.
result:

if you need a blend file, let me know.
